# Teamcity Unity library folder

Tags: unity-game-engine, continuous-integration, teamcity

I am using teamcity to build my Unity3d projects. When I am selecting branch in custom build or when build is triggered from "not master branch" git performs clean, and it removes my Library folder. I need to persist this folder because it is a cache that builds a huge amount of time. When I stay on master, everything is fine and this cache is reused. How can I do this? I want this folder to be shared between my branches.

I tried to create multiple VSC roots, but it copies my repo for every branch. I also disabled all "clean" options that I found in settings. But nothing helps

Answer (score 1):

You could try one of these:

1. In VCS Root settings you could set **Clean Policy** to **Never**. It sets whether and when TeamCity should exec **git clean** in working dir. Default value is "**On branch change**" which I guess is your case. But it means that you should manually clean your working dir from build artifacts. For more information see [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/git.html#GitAgentSettings)
2. You could use [Unity Accelerator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAccelerator.html)
3. You could backup your Library folder in the end of every build and restore in the beginning of the next one

Comment: Thanks, first solution is not working, but third is nice, added these two steps to my script